# Strip off prefix in Zuul API gateway

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I am trying to configure an API call router using zuul that forwards calls .
There are two services: the users service is using path versioning, i.e. `/v1/users`, `/v2/users`, ...
The accounts service does not use path versioning, thus all routes omit the `v*` prefix (`/accounts`).

To provide a common interface, I'd like to accept calls to `/v*/accounts` in my api router and forward them to `/accounts` on my accounts service.
Calls to `/v*/user/` should be forwarded to the users service as they are.

My application.yml looks something like this

```
zuul:
  routes:
    users: 
      path: /v*/users/**
      url: ${microservices.usersServiceUrl}
      stripPrefix: false
    accounts: 
      path: /v*/accounts/**
      url: ${microservices.accountsServiceUrl}
      stripPrefix: true
```

This does not have the intended effect, unfortunately.
Nothing from the account paths in stripped and they are forwarded as they are.

If I remove the regex (`v*`) and put `path: /v1/accounts/**` instead, the entire prefix `/v1/accounts` is stripped off. Apparently a regex prevents the prefix being stripped off, thus putting `path: /v1/**/accounts/**` works. However, I would like to avoid naming all versions explicitly as our API is evolving quite rapidly at the moment.

Using the global `zuul.prefix` did not help either, as you can only globally decide to strip it off or leave it intact AFAIK.

I mostly relied [on this documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html).

Is there a better way to specify the format of the forwarded URL?